# TypeScript - type intersection & this keyword

Tags: types, typescript

What is the difference between:

```
interface MyType {
    f<T>(other: T): this & T;
}
```

and

```
interface MyType {
    f<T>(other: T): MyType & T;
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` type depends on the implementing class, so given the first definition, the following will typecheck:

```
class Foo implements MyType {
    f<T>(other: T): T & this { ... }
    g(): string { return "only in foo"; }
}

var foo: Foo
var ff = foo.f("dsklf");
var s: string = ff.g();
```

since `ff` has type `Foo & string` and therefore is a subtype of `Foo`.

Given the second definition of `MyType`, `ff.g()` will not typecheck since `g` is not defined on `MyType & string`.